# SharePoint CRUD Operations in a JavaScript Batch Opertation

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, crud

Is there a way, possibly through the OfficePnP js-core library, to have a javascript model that represents a set of list items that knows when it's dirty and can commit that back to SharePoint in a batch operation?

In other words, I'd like to add, remove, and update javascript objects from a collection then just pass that off to something that will commit the proper actions to the SharePoint server via REST.

Answer (score 2):

> in other words, I'd like to add, remove, and update javascript objects
>   from a collection **then just pass that off to something that will
>   commit the proper actions** to the SharePoint server via REST.

SharePoint itself is that '**something**'

When you add your own layer/tier (with REST or JSOM)
you will have to write that '**something**' yourself

Libraries like PnP Core JS make the writing easier (including batching)
but it does not do the work for you.

In PnP they call that 'something' Business Objects:

for insipiration see: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Extending-with-Custom-Business-Objects

Answer (score 0):

I used to do batch operations using SharePoint REST API. The below article I was referring to

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis

If you want to use PnP JS Core, I found the following article:

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Batching